# How to automatically enter the sheet name in a cell, containing maximum value of a data in a fixed cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Suppose I have a cell C5, and I want to display the sheet name in a cell of the first sheet, which has the highest value of C5 among all the sheets in that 
workbook.

**Note, not the maximum value of C5, but the sheet name**

**I don't want this:**

=MAX('first_sheet_name:last_sheet_name'!B1)

**I already know this and I am asking for something else**

Answer (score 1):

You can use *VLOOKUP()*

First we create a table for *VLOOKUP()* to use.  Using the *Name Manager* in the *Data Tab*, we create a `Name` called *Sheets* and assign this formula to it:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),"["&GET.WORKBOOK(16)&"]","")
```

[image]

Then pick some cell in any sheet, say **I2** and enter:

```
=IF(COUNTA(Sheets)>=ROW($A1),INDEX(Sheets, ROW($A1)), "")
```

and copy down. *(this creates the list of sheet names)*

In **H2** enter:

=IF(I2="","",INDIRECT(I2 & "!C5"))

and copy down.  Cols **H** and **I** are the lookup table:

[image]

Finally this lookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(H:H),H:I,2,FALSE)
```

retrieves the sheetname

Answer (score 0):

Returning the Sheet name without using VBA is a bit tricky.
One thing you can do is to manually compare cells and sheets, but this is only feasible if you have few sheets and cells.

```
=IF(Sheet1!C5>Sheet2!C5;IF(Sheet1!C5>Sheet3!C5;"Sheet1";"Sheet3");IF(Sheet2!C5>Sheet3!C5;"Sheet2";"Sheet3"))
```

A simple comparison between the values of C5 in "Sheet1", "Sheet2", and "Sheet3".

The only way I know of to display a sheet name, is by using something similar to:

```
=MID(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("]";CELL("filename";A1))+1;255)
```

This will only return the sheet of the specified cell, in this case, the sheet the code is on.

Or in VBA, something similar to:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim cellAddress As String
Set cell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
cellAddress = cell.Parent.Name
```

Now we just have to combine that with the right cell.
Haven't figured that part out yet.